# Getting a mysql syntax error but can't see the problem

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native

I've just started creating a gym tracking app using React Native, Typescript, Node, and MySQL to improve my backend (by backend I mean my proficiency in backend development, I'm not creating the app to track my squats in the hopes of improving *my* backend, although it could do with some work. Also by gym tracking app I mean essentially a replacement for a gym tracking notepad with some added graphs etc.)

I've created a route that posts the user's latest set with all the usual things like weight, reps, etc.

This is the function that posts to the db:

```js
export const addLogEntry = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/logEntries', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: req.body.id }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  })
    .then((response: any) => response.json())
    .then((data: any) => {
      req.body.entry.id = data.length + 1;
      req.body.entry.userId = req.body.id;
      const {
        id,
        set,
        logId,
        weight,
        reps,
        time,
        rest,
        exerciseId,
        userId,
      } = req.body.entry;
      console.log(id, set, logId, weight, reps, time, rest, exerciseId, userId);
      connection.query(
        `INSERT into logEntries(id, set, logId, weight, reps, time, rest, exerciseId, userId) VALUES(${id}, ${set}, ${logId}, ${weight}, ${reps}, ${time}, ${rest}, ${exerciseId}, ${userId})`,
        function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          res.send('');
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
    });
};
```

Here's the body of the request:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "entry": {
        "set": 2,
        "logId": 2,
        "weight": 82.5,
        "reps": 12,
        "time": 0,
        "rest": 60,
        "exerciseId": 1
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the table structure:

[image: logEntries table structure]

And this is the error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set, logId, weight, reps, time, rest, exerciseId, userId) VALUES(9, 2, 2, 82.5, ' at line 1
```

Does anyone have any idea? I feel like the fact that it's a syntax error means it's most likely staring me in the face.

Comment: Study [MySQL reserved words list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Try enclosing field names in back-ticks

Comment: @Akina That was it, thankyou! The reserved words were 'time' and 'set'